# Replacing variable product pricing in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the price range that is shown for variable products in the WooCommerce site I'm working on. On non-product pages I want to replace it with "from: [lowest price]" and on the product page I'd like to replace it simply with the price of the selected variation.

Any ideas how I can get it working that way?

Thanks,

Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible way to do what you want is that you change it on non-product page and remove it from product page. On product page when you select a variaion, its price and remaining stock is shown below the dropdown. So there is no need for you to show it above. If you still want to do it you will need a js solution.

**Try this, this is tested solution.** I have commented the cases for better guidance and changing if you want.

```
function sr_change_variable_price($price, $product) 
{
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && !is_product() ) 
    {
        return 'From: '.$product->get_variation_price( 'min' ); // if variable product and non-product page
    } else if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && is_product() )
    {
        return '';  // if variable product and product page
    } else
    {
        return $price;  // other cases
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sr_change_variable_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It works as far as variable products are concerned, however, the price for normal (i.e. non-variable) products no longer shows.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. There was a typo that i overlooked. Have edited the answer. Please try again.

Comment: That did the job, fantastic! Thanks @shazyriver

Comment: Hi again @shazriver! I just noticed that related products on the product page no longer have prices. Is there a way of updating the code snippet to ensure the "from: " price is retained for this block?